# Microsoft Translate API for Android gives UnknownHostException

Tags: java, android, language-translation, microsoft-translator, unknown-host

I have tried the following code to implement a translator app using Microsoft Translator API library found [here](https://code.google.com/p/microsoft-translator-java-api/). I have a working internet connection and I have generated the a valid client id and secret but whenever I try to run the code I get the `java.net.UnknownHostException`.

My code:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
             StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
             Translate.setClientId("Screened for the question"); //Change this
               Translate.setClientSecret("I have screened the client secret to ask in SO"); //change

               final TextView  text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
               Button Trans1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.trans);
               Trans1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
               public void onClick(View view) {
                   String word = "Hello";
                   try {
                   translatedText = Translate.execute(word, Language.ENGLISH, Language.GERMAN);
                      // text.setText(translatedText);
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
               });
```

My Stack trace:

```
04-11 14:19:41.711: W/System.err(3084): java.lang.Exception: [microsoft-translator-api] Error retrieving translation : Unable to resolve host "datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net": No address associated with hostname
04-11 14:19:41.711: W/System.err(3084):     at com.memetix.mst.MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.retrieveString(MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.java:202)
04-11 14:19:41.711: W/System.err(3084):     at com.memetix.mst.translate.Translate.execute(Translate.java:61)
04-11 14:19:41.711: W/System.err(3084):     at com.example.tanslator.TransActivity$1.onClick(TransActivity.java:45)
04-11 14:19:41.711: W/System.err(3084):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3571)
04-11 14:19:41.711: W/System.err(3084):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14247)
04-11 14:19:41.711: W/System.err(3084):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-11 14:19:41.711: W/System.err(3084):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-11 14:19:41.711: W/System.err(3084):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-11 14:19:41.711: W/System.err(3084):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
04-11 14:19:41.711: W/System.err(3084):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 14:19:41.711: W/System.err(3084):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-11 14:19:41.711: W/System.err(3084):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
04-11 14:19:41.711: W/System.err(3084):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
04-11 14:19:41.711: W/System.err(3084):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 14:19:41.711: W/System.err(3084): Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net": No address associated with hostname
04-11 14:19:41.711: W/System.err(3084):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:400)
04-11 14:19:41.711: W/System.err(3084):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
04-11 14:19:41.711: W/System.err(3084):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
04-11 14:19:41.711: W/System.err(3084):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
04-11 14:19:41.711: W/System.err(3084):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
04-11 14:19:41.711: W/System.err(3084):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
04-11 14:19:41.711: W/System.err(3084):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
04-11 14:19:41.721: W/System.err(3084):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
04-11 14:19:41.721: W/System.err(3084):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
04-11 14:19:41.721: W/System.err(3084):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:460)
04-11 14:19:41.721: W/System.err(3084):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:441)
04-11 14:19:41.721: W/System.err(3084):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
04-11 14:19:41.721: W/System.err(3084):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
04-11 14:19:41.721: W/System.err(3084):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
04-11 14:19:41.721: W/System.err(3084):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:188)
04-11 14:19:41.721: W/System.err(3084):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:280)
04-11 14:19:41.721: W/System.err(3084):     at com.memetix.mst.MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.getToken(MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.java:133)
04-11 14:19:41.721: W/System.err(3084):     at com.memetix.mst.MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.retrieveResponse(MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.java:160)
04-11 14:19:41.721: W/System.err(3084):     at com.memetix.mst.MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.retrieveString(MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.java:199)
04-11 14:19:41.721: W/System.err(3084):     ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had this same issue using this api ,it worked after changing the line

`translatedText = Translate.execute(word, Language.ENGLISH, Language.GERMAN);`
to

```
translatedText = Translate.execute(word, Language.GERMAN);
```